# Printing results to a csv file at the end of each while loop printing duplicates

Tags: jmeter

I'm using a BeanShell PostProcessor to append results to a .csv file at the end of each loop in my test, however when I open the file I find that it has appended more entries than it has looped through. The extra entries are repeats of other rows.

```
FinalCount= vars.get("finalCount");
Loop = vars.get("loop");

f = new FileOutputStream("/tests/results.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(Loop + "," + FinalCount);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

It may happen due to:

- PostProcessor Scope: you placed PostProcessor in wrong place so each sampler triggers its execution
- Most likely: PostProcessor is executed by each Thread (virtual user) and you want it to be executed only once

I would recommend the following:

1. Place PostProcessor **as a child** of the last sampler
2. Amend your code so it will write a line only if executed by i.e. first thread like:

   ```
   if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 0) {
   //your code here
   }
   ```

`ctx` is a shorthand to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class and [getThreadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum()) method returns the number of current thread.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for  more information on using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) from Beanshell scripts.